# Subtrees of Binary Trees in a range Haskell

Tags: haskell, recursion, tree

I have a Binary Tree defined as the following:

```
data BSTree = Void | BSNode BSTree Integer BSTree
```

and would like to write a function

```
subTree:: Integer -> Integer -> BSTree -> BSTree
```

which returns all subset of trees with a <= key < b.

I tried the following

```
subTree:: Integer -> Integer -> BSTree -> BSTree
subTree a b Void = Void
subTree a b (BSNode leftTree key rightTree) 
    | key < a = BSNode Void key (subTree key b rightTree)
    | b < key = BSNode (subTree a key leftTree) key Void
    | a <= key && b > key = BSNode (subTree a key leftTree) key (subTree key b rightTree)
```

but do not get the correct output. Could someone point out the flaw in my logic?

Comment: Hint: If `key < a`, you still return a `BSNode` that *contains* the `key`. The same for `b < key`.

Comment: what's it to do with the height of the tree?

Comment: Apologies, Brain fade on the title. @WillemVanOnsem That is true but Im not sure what I should be using instead.

Comment: @AdityaSubramanian: you recurse on the right subtree, *without* constructing a node at that level.

Comment: Alright ofcourse! Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

I  each step of the recursion, you should provide `a` and `b` arguments:

```
data BSTree = Void | BSNode BSTree Integer BSTree deriving Show

subTree:: Integer -> Integer -> BSTree -> BSTree
subTree a b Void = Void
subTree a b (BSNode leftTree key rightTree) 
 | key < a = --your logic here
 | b < key = -- your logic here
 | a <= key && b > key = BSNode (subTree a b leftTree) key (subTree a b rightTree)

t1 = BSNode Void 5 Void
t2 = BSNode Void 6 Void
t3 = BSNode Void 7 Void
t4 = BSNode t1 8 (BSNode t1 7 t2)
```

With this example:

```
   subTree 6 10 t4
=> BSNode Void 8 (BSNode Void 7 (BSNode Void 6 Void))
```